# Bootstrap .active state submenu doesn't work correctly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am implementing [this theme](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin/), which has a main nav, and a submenu nav.

I am having trouble getting the `.active` class to correctly display.

When I load the page it's correct: 
[image]

But when I click on another page, e.g. clients: 
[image]
Dashboard remains highlighted.

So I added a bit of jQuery:

```
$(".side-nav a").on("click", function(){
    $(".side-nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
```

And this does cause the active class to move to client, but only while it's loading the page, it then goes back to Dashboard.

Here is the output (on page Clients):

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="/"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/clients"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Clients</a>
            </li>
```

[Here is a fiddle,](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18730/) but you won't see error since it only shows the front page.

Clearly I'm missing a trick here.

**Update** 
I am using a layout page (Java Spring) so this is how my layout page looks:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
....
<!-- Sidebar Menu Items - These collapse to the responsive navigation menu on small screens -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="/"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/clients"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Clients</a>
            </li>
            ...
</nav>
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!--here is where all my content goes-->
        <section layout:fragment="mainContent">
            <!-- Content replaced by each page's content fragment -->
            <p>This section will not render, overriden by child</p>
        </section>
        ...
```

And then my clients.html page would look like this:

```
...
<body>
<div layout:fragment="mainContent">
    ...
</div>
```

The hard coded .active class is the problem, since when the page jumps from one page to the next, it loads up the layout and sees the hardcoded dashboard `.active` class there.

Comment: Do you have a different .html page for each page? For example, is the dashboard page dashboard.html and the charts page charts.html? If so, you have the "active" class hard coded in your html on the dashboard page so when you move to the charts page the active class will go back to the dashboard. If you have a different .html page for each page, just move the "active" class in the html to the current page

Comment: @JoshSalazar Yes they are on different pages but I am using a 'layout page', so the nav bar is loaded from layout, not from the current html page. I'll update my answer to show you how the page looks

Comment: @JoshSalazar I see what's happening. How can I bypass this then? You're right, every time my page loads, it sees `dashboard` has the hardcoded `.active` class so it is loading that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've come up with a pretty ugly solution but it does seem to be working.

With JQuery I load a class the `active` on the current item and then remove the active class when a user leaves the page.

I had to make a minor change to my list structure adding some Ids:

```
<ul id="submenu" class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
    <li id="submenu-dashboard" >
        <a href="/"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a>
            </li>
    <li id="submenu-clients">
        <a href="/clients"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Clients</a>
    </li>
    ...
```

JQuery:

```
//removes active state from all pages before it unloads
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    $('#submenu li').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    });
});

//adds active state to the current page on load
$(document).ready(function () {
    var currentPage = $(location).attr('pathname').replace('/', '');
    $('#submenu li').each(function () {
        var itemId = $(this).attr('id');

        //we check the currentPage matches the Id
        if (itemId.indexOf(currentPage) >= 0) {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Note: the id of the `li` element **MUST** contain the URL of the page.